# SqlHierarchyId.Parse(string) returns {NULL} hierarchy in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

Trying to create, update and read HierarchyId from SqlServer using EFCore in .NET Core 2.2

Seems like whatever I do the constructor returns null,using dotnetstandard libraries results in error when the data is read.

Using the official Microsoft.SqlServer.Types:

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.1016.290' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

```cs
public class User
{
  [Key]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public SqlHierarchyId Hierarchy { get; set; }
  //etc.
}
```

```cs
user.Hierarchy = SqlHierarchyId.Parse(new SqlString("/" + user.UserId + "/"));
if(user.Hierachy.IsNull) {throw new Exception()}
user.Hierarchy = SqlHierarchyId.Parse(new SqlString("/0/"));
if(user.Hierachy.IsNull) {throw new Exception()}
```

Both constructors above should return a valid hierarchy.

When using dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (standard compiled, in an attempt to bodge around) the above works, but this:

```cs
var foo = this.context.UserSocials.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == userId)?.Hierarchy;
```

When a valid hierarchyid is read from the server program throws

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What is the current and correct way of using HierarchyId in EFCore?

Comment: [See also](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/issues/22). There currently simply is no "correct" way of using it until Microsoft decides to actually port it (the code isn't in a repo that accepts contributions either). I expect this will not actually happen in the existing packages but instead become part of the [new `SqlClient` implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient), which EF Core does not yet use. ...basically, give it some time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, it's just about what I feared, though I was hoping someone had found a workaround.

Comment: As a workaround you can put a view with INSEAD OF triggers in front of your table and expose the `hierarchyid` column as a `varchar`.  Then either work with it as a string on the client or use a Value Conversion to convert the string to the 3rd-party client-side HierarchID type.